# How to kill the background process automatically with no `kill pid`?

Tags: python, shell, process

I run the background process in my vps console  with the command .

```
nohup  python  /home/test.py  &
```

When program is over , input  `ps aux`  in my putty console ，the message displayed in the screen.

```
root      3513  0.1  2.9  24296 15004 ?        S    11:51   0:00 python /home/test
```

How can i kill the process with no `kill 3513` ?

Comment: what do you mean by when program is over? It's still running in the background, isn't it?

Comment: i get the result by the program ,but  it's still running in the background.

Comment: maybe your program isn't over. can u show us ur code?